# Mounting outdoors camera using aluminum 5052

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, structures, strength, aluminum

I designed a simple U shape 2mm sheet metal bent mount for a 4kg outdoors CCTV camera. The mount was accidentally produced from 5052-H32 Aluminum instead of 6061-T6.

Is it common to use 5052 aluminium for such structural use-case? Or it is better to reproduce the mount? A static linear analysis shows that there is a factor of safety of 1.6 with g factor of 12.

Comment: Personally, I’d want more than a 1.6X safety factor.

Comment: Whose fault was the accident? If the manufacturer then what is stopping you asking for it in 6061 at no extra cost?

Comment: The thing is that the cameras are already mounted, and it is difficult to replace the mount now. I try to evaluate the risk of leaving the situation as is, and unfortunately I am not familiar with 5052 alloys. Does 5052-H32 is used for structural purposes? I heard it is used for marine structures due to its good corrosion resistance. Does 2 mm bended sheet metal of 5052H32 is a common practice for 4kg weight mounting?

Comment: How did you determine the G factor? Sorry if this is a stupid question but does that mean the number of G's the structure will experience?

Answer (score 1):

A quick check on the net shows the 5052 has a lower strength than the 6061 , mostly caused by heat-treatment. Tensile is 25% lower, yield is 30 % lower ; nominal properties.

Comment: 6061’s yield strength is 40% higher than 5052. I think that is more than “a little”.